# Software Center missing or just not working?

Tags: software-center

**I'm not sure if the software center is just broken or if it's missing.**

I think it was removed from the bottom tab, the one at the bottom of the screen, by my brother. I went through applications and found a program titled "Software" but nothing specifically titled "Software Center" or "Ubuntu Software Center" can be found.

It has been a long time since I have used the software center to get anything, so I'm wondering if it that is the correct program or if it's not.

When I open it, the "All" tab reads:

> No Application Data Found

The "Installed" tab is blank and doesn't show anything. The "Update" tab claims everything is up to date but when I refresh it, it never finishes.

**Is something wrong or am I just doing it wrong, *again*?**

Comment: Again, Please fully update your system. That's all you need.

Comment: This happened  on my son's PC right after he did a update to 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reinstall the **Software Center** by pasting this long line into the Terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T):

**sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center software-properties-common software-properties-gtk**